# Parsing CSV in PHP - grabbing all siblings when condition is met

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, fgetcsv

I'm trying to grab the values of an array when a certain condition is met. I seem to have found myself in a real pickle and am hoping there is help on this matter. I'm still new to PHP and solidifying my skills in arrays and loops. I'm using php and trying to parse a csv file that will be uploaded daily. I then need to parse this csv file and insert the values into our client reporting system.

```
$rows = array();    
$file = file('prerolldaily.csv');   
$rows = $file;
foreach($rows as $rowsInArray){
    $details = str_getcsv($rowsInArray);
    var_dump($details);
    foreach($details as $key => $value){
        //var_dump($value);
        if ($value === 'CLIENT A') {
            // Grab all sibling values
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the var_dump for $details...

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string 'switch active/paused CLIENT A CLIENT A Sites Ads Pre-roll (30s)' (length=69)
  1 => string 'Day 12 out of 19 Nov 8, 2013 Nov 26, 2013' (length=41)
  2 => string '$20.00' (length=6)
  3 => string '$50.00' (length=6)
  4 => string '3,360' (length=5)
  5 => string '12' (length=2)
  6 => string '0.36%' (length=5)
  7 => string '57%' (length=3)
  8 => string '$14.46' (length=6)
  9 => string '$48.58' (length=6)
  10 => string 'edit placement copy placement delete see report attach ad' (length=57)
  11 => string 'CLIENT A' (length=11)

array (size=12)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
  8 => string '' (length=0)
  9 => string '' (length=0)
  10 => string '' (length=0)
  11 => string '' (length=0)

array (size=12)
  0 => string 'switch active/paused CLIENT B CLIENT B Sites Ads Pre-roll (30s)' (length=91)
  1 => string 'Day 13 out of 20 Nov 7, 2013 Nov 26, 2013' (length=41)
  2 => string '$20.00' (length=6)
  3 => string '$50.00' (length=6)
  4 => string '3,246' (length=5)
  5 => string '8' (length=1)
  6 => string '0.25%' (length=5)
  7 => string '61%' (length=3)
  8 => string '$14.88' (length=6)
  9 => string '$48.30' (length=6)
  10 => string 'edit placement copy placement delete see report attach ad' (length=57)
  11 => string 'CLIENT B' (length=22)
```

Any help on how to target the siblings when the CLIENT is met, would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for.. can you provide the layout of your CSV?

Comment: I don't either understand. Some kind of expected result could also help...

Comment: So when one of the arrays has a value "CLIENT A", you want to get all the other values in that same array?

Comment: I'll try to clarify... There is a csv file that is generated daily with results from a marketing campaign for several clients. This csv file needs to be parsed and inserted into a database with a unique identifier for the client along with it's appropriate data, thus why I need to locate the proper client within the arrays and grab all data related to that client.

Comment: @eskimo, that is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly

```
$rows = array();    
$file = file('prerolldaily.csv');   
$rows = $file;
$c = 0; 
$selected_array = "";

foreach($rows as $rowsInArray){
    $details = str_getcsv($rowsInArray);

    foreach($details as $key => $value){
        foreach ($value as $k => $v){
            if ($v == "CLIENT A"){
                $selected_array = $c;
            }
        }
        $c++;
    }
}

print_r($details[$selected_array]);
```

So, we are creating a count (`$c`) which will keep track of which level in the main array we are in (`$details_array)`, and an empty variable to store which array is the *correct* one. We loop through the main array (`$details_array`), and in that loop, loop through the sub arrays values.

If we find the matching value, we set the `$selected_array` value to the count (`$c`) as this is the key for the array in which our value was found

This can be further optimized by breaking out of the loop when the correct array is found based on the values, but that depends on your use case (whether you need the outer loop to continue or not)

Comment: I grabbed your code and I believe I understand what's being attempted here through your description. I am getting this error message, any further thoughts... Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\api_integration\video_preroll\testToXML.php on line 12

Comment: Is line 12 the second array loop (`foreach ($value as $k => $v)`)?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion... I'm also getting this 'Undefined index: in C:\wamp\www\api_integration\video_preroll\testToXML.php on line 19' for the following line... print_r($details[$selected_array]);

Comment: The second error is because the `$selected_array` is not being set. Try doing a `print_r($value)` instead of the `foreach ($value as $k => $v)` loop. Does that print out an array?

Comment: adding the print_r prints every value in the entire array

Comment: I just grabbed your latest iteration, but it's still showing an invalid argument supplied error for the: foreach ($value as $k => $v) line